# How to keep frozen French fries crispy?

Tags: deep-frying

There are a lot of frozen French fry recipes on Google and YouTube, but none stay crispy after defrost. I have tried many. After 2-4 month they become soft and pale. I doubt there are some chemicals which can keep their taste and crispy texture. Such as potatopro or McCain supplier. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely, your issue is that your fries don't freeze quickly enough!
First of all, potatoes are VERY tricky for freezing anyway: their cell-structure takes REALLY badly to freezing, making them change texture and sometimes taste a lot.
The problem is reduced, but not removed, by cooking them first, but even then, they tend to react badly.
Now, what do commercial fries have that you don't? They can actually do shock-freezing! This means they can freeze their fries REALLY quickly, which highly reduces the damage to the cells. So, sadly your best shot may be: buy some dry ice to use for freezing your fries.

Comment: Thanks a lot Layna. Then I must plan to buy a good refrigerator. Can you suggest some brand? Can I freeze the fries or potato after mixing  some testy ingredients, such as paprika?

Comment: @user65822 ensure your current refrigerator has one of its shelves empty , put a piece of tin foil straight onto the freezing elements throw it straight on there while still lukewarm.

Comment: @Fabby : while still lukewarm?  Typically when you want to avoid ice crystals, you shill it down to fridge temp, *then* freeze it.  You can put a sheet pan in the freezer ahead of time, so that has some thermal mass to soak up the heat.  (but the dry ice suggestion might be better ... or liquid nitrogen, if you want to spend way too much money on this project)

Comment: I single-fry them first, then fast-freeze @Joe, thus lukewarm thus smaller ice crystals as they don't have time to grow. (works for me!)

Answer (score 0):

To my experience I throw them in the fryer right out the freezer (with oil at 350F)
they get that golden look and crispy texture. Wouldn't recommend do it at home with a pot and oil unless you have one of those little fryers